# How do I escape Char(1) in XML?

Tags: xml, jsp, escaping, freemarker

I have a Toshiba printer, and the manual of this printer give me this information:

```
ASCII       Dec.    Hex.    Description
----------------------------------------------------------
ESC w 1/0   119     77      Enable / Disable double height
```

I want to print a ticket with my printer. The format of this document is *ftl. Then, I want to write COPY with double letter size high

I need to escape this element: ESC w 1, the number 1 I need to escape of this way: char(1), but I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking, please clarify your question by possible inputs and desired output !

Comment: I want to print a ticket with my printer. The format of this document is *ftl. Then, I want to write COPY with double letter size high

Comment: What tool are you using ,  FreeMarker?

Comment: yes, I'm using FreeMarker

Comment: I am not familiar with FreeMarker , but is [this](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_escape.html) be helpful?

Comment: no, I need write text with this language but more high and bold

Answer (score 1):

That would be `${'\x1b'}w1` and `${'\x1b'}w0`. If you need it a lot, you could define a macro like `<#macro big>${'\x1b'}w1<#nested>${'\x1b'}w0</#macro>` and then use `<@big>something</@big>`.

Comment: Now, I have this code in my config.xml: <map><entry key="doubleSize" value="&lt;!STRPOS_ESC&gt;w1" /></map> And I need to escape the number 1. How I could do it with your code?

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to escape `1`. There's nothing to escape there, as it isn't a character with special meaning. Looking at that XML you have to `?replace` `"<!STRPOS_ESC>"` with `"\x1b"`, though I don't know why's that special symbol used, when you could just have `value="&#x1b;w1"`, and then you can print that value as is.